# Print preview slow in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, printing, 23.04

When I try to launch a print preview in programs such as Okular, Thunderbird, or Firefox, the print window opens and stay on the loading "Preparing Preview" for a very long time. After a while a "Program is not responding" window show off and proposes to wait or force stop. If I wait more the print options finally appears. It could take several minutes.

I was originally on Ubuntu 22.04, I tried updating to 23.04 but the bug is still here.
Has someone faced the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator Is it better now?

Comment: It seems unchanged. What is the "Program does not respond" window ssy? Whivh program isn't responding?